# Salesforce launch LWC from formula field from inside Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, formula-field, customer-community

I need the ability to launch a flow inside a modal from a formula field. (Why from a formula? Because I need to launch the flow from a button/link of sorts on a managed-package custom LWC)

I've achieved this functionality beautifully in the Internal Salesforce org, but it does not work in a Community because they don't support URL hacking. **How else can I do this?**

The only solution that I can think of is to [launch a LWC from the formula field](https://www.forcetrails.com/2020/07/how-to-open-lwc-from-formula-field.html), and have the flow contained within the LWC. The only articles/examples I can find of this are based on an internal org's URL structure:

```
HYPERLINK("/lightning/cmp/c__yrlAddressableAura?c__recordId="+Id, "Label for link", "_self")
```

**Will this URL structure work in a Community to launch the LWC?**

Comment: You seem to have the URL structure you want to try and use - have you attempted to test this method?

Comment: @VictorL. I have not - trying to avoid going through the effort of developing a LWC before I know that it is theoretically possible. But the way its looking, I may need to just spin up a very basic component just to test it.